# How should I make reference to App\User model in a laravel packaging when testing

Tags: laravel, testing, package

I'm coding a laravel package, that interact with User model.

When I test it in browser, everything is OK, because App\User exists, but when I test my plugin, `App\User` doesn't exists.

So it fails. I replaced all references of `App\User` to `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` but my relations fail, my factories fails.

for instance, the User factory:

```
$factory->define(\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name'               => $faker->name,
        'email'              => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at'  => now(),
        'password'           => '$2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm', // secret
        'remember_token'     => str_random(10),
        'firstname'          => $faker->firstname,
        'lastname'           => $faker->lastName,
    ];
});
```

Won't work with `\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User::class`, because it doesn't have all custom fields: `email_verified_at`,`firstname`,`lastname`,etc.

So my tests fail:

```
11) Xoco70\LaravelTournaments\Tests\SingleEliminationWPrelimTest::it_can_generate_prelim_tree_with_12_fighters
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table users has no column named email_verified_at (SQL: insert into "users" ("name", "email", "email_verified_at", "password", "remember_token", "firstname", "lastname", "updated_at", "created_at") values (user, jennifer86@example.org, 2018-10-11 09:14:17, $2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm, KZmf72JC9D, Buster, Hackett, 2018-10-11 09:14:17, 2018-10-11 09:14:17))
```

or my relations:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User::class, 'competitor', 'championship_id')
        ->withPivot('confirmed')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Won't work neither.

How should I manage it ?

Comment: How does your package interact with the User class? Is it by a trait or does someone add config? You'll need to provide some more color on the specific test and how your package interacts with the User model

Comment: All my tests are failing, this is not specific. I don't use traits. 2 specific cases are failing, factories and relationships. I don't know what to add, please tell me.

Comment: Depending on the usage, you could just mock the User model.

Comment: In this case, the plugin comes with a controller that is use for demo purpose. The controller generate fake users and with them, it generates a tournament tree based on user's input